# How can I compare corresponding items in a python dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, comparison

For example, I have two dictionaries:

```
a = {
    'Letters': ['Alpha', 'Beta', 'Theta'],
    'Animals': ['Dog', 'Cat', 'Ox']
}
```

I need to satisfy a condition such that I return a list so that only the values in 'Letters' that are greater than/equal to/less than (as specified) the corresponding values in 'Animals' are included.

Basically, is there a simple way to only compare the values in the list at matching indexes?

'Alpha' vs. 'Dog'

'Beta' vs. 'Cat'

'Theta' vs. 'Ox'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get corresponding pairs, you can use `zip` (think of how a jacket zipper behaves):

```
>>> a = {'Letters': ['Alpha', 'Beta', 'Theta'], 'Animals': ['Dog', 'Cat', 'Ox']}
>>> zip(a["Letters"], a["Animals"])
[('Alpha', 'Dog'), ('Beta', 'Cat'), ('Theta', 'Ox')]
```

If you don't care about the order, only about the correspondence, you could reduce this to

```
>>> zip(*a.values())
[('Dog', 'Alpha'), ('Cat', 'Beta'), ('Ox', 'Theta')]
```

(In Python 3, make that `list(zip(..))` to get a list, but you can still iterate over it, as in `for pair in zip(*a.values()): print(pair)`, without materializing it.)

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
>>> a = {'Letters': ['Alpha', 'Beta', 'Theta'], 'Animals': ['Dog', 'Cat', 'Ox']}
>>> [ letter for letter, animal in zip( a['Letters'], a['Animals']) if letter > animal]
['Theta']
>>> [ letter for letter, animal in zip( a['Letters'], a['Animals']) if letter < animal]
['Alpha', 'Beta']
>>>
```